# Multiple visual entries in urdf

Tags: ros, urdf, robot-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to have multiple visual entries in an urdf link?

If yes, how? For me, it seems to only take the first entry.

The same would go for collision models and maybe inertia.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10913/multiple-visual-entries-in-urdf/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a discussion about this [on the mailing list](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Robot-model-meshes-in-RViz-td966343.html) in the past, with a [ticket submitted](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4270) and [newer more general ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4262). It seems like it is implemented in robot_model trunk (and waiting for release in e-turtle?).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-17**:
The hacky/simple way is using the editor tool and then correcting the links in the source.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-08-16**:
Ah thanks! I just can't get used to the syntax of the markdown here - thus the need to fall back to the editor tool.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-08-16**:
I fixed the links for you. For some reason, the "add link" tool prepends an "http://" to things that start with "https://". You can see the error if you look at the actual markdown for the link. I usually just insert links as markdown and skip the GUI tool to avoid weirdness like that.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-08-16**:
I can't seem to post these links correctly - they show up OK in the preview but look messed up in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the short answer is no.

However, you can create a second link with the same origin that has additional properties.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-17**:
I will do this for now. Seems a bit hacky to me as it is actually one part.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The released electric robot_model do parse multiple visuals.  You can retrieve them using `urdf::Link::getVisuals(const std::string &group_name)`.  Please take a look at the [code api](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/urdf_interface/html/classurdf_1_1Link.html).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2